# Detecting Operation Sign in a String Java

Tags: java, data-structures, expression

Currently I have a string where it signifies an expression (i.e., "2+4*8/2") and  is there a way to convert this to a regular expression that is NOT a string so it can return 18?

If not, is there a way to detect what kind of operator it is at a given character?

In Java would help.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "a regular expression that is not a string"? Do you want to evaluate the expression?

Comment: What? Are you actually asking to compile this to a mathematical expression and run it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form

Comment: Java *itself* does not offer such a method. However, Java has a built-in Javascript engine that offers the usual *eval* method. So as long as the equation stays as simple as this you can use this to parse and evaluate the equation. For details, refer to the linked duplicate.

Comment: Please note that you should do a quick research prior to posting a question on SO, thanks (see [ask]).

Comment: Note that a "regular expression" is a thing that's entirely different to what you're looking for. You might cause some confusion if you try to explain it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly what you can do is you can convert this String into a char Array and you can perform your own implementation because conmpiler cant convert your expression into a mathemathical form....